# Written forms to sql including multiple yes, no other

Tags: sql, forms, database-design, normalization, relational

I am designing a database for written forms that are filled out each time a person visits an office. i already have:

patient:
**patient_id**, fname, lname, gender etc

adult
*patient_id*, occupation etc

child 
*patient_id*, school etc

I'm supposed to store form data that is written up each time a person visits which is approximately 20 questions.

e.g:
The written form has questions like:

> YES / NO - Any indication of hearing difficulty? If YES, which ear is
>   involved? R___ L___ Both___
>
> YES / NO - Any head injury? ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
>
> YES / NO - Scheduled for surgery? if YES what type and when?
>
> ---

What would be the best way to implement this so it's normalized and properly structured? Also any suggestions for column names as this will be a lot of data? I'm figuring so far that i may need two tables like child_info and adult_info that will get foreign key from person, to store this data

Comment: patient and relatives gonna have exactly the same form? Or form for patient have got more personal data than those for relatives?

Comment: adult and child tables are sub tables of patient. So they'll have different questions @Borys

Comment: have you thought about using inheritance in this case? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-inherit.html

Answer (score 0):

First, have a 'questions' table;

- question_id
- question_text
- answer_type (this may be a foreign key to a question_types table)

This makes it easy to add or update questions in the future.

To hold the answers for a given patient, have an 'answers' table;

- patient_id
- question_id
- answer
- notes

This means the answers are separate from the adult or child info, but are still linked to the patient.